# Solving analytic solution to 1st, 2nd and 3rd order

Tags: cosmology, computational-physics, dark-energy

I'm currently reading a review paper on quintessence (https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1961) and in §3.1 he plots the evolution of the equation of state parameter $w$ with the scale factor $a$. He produces a plot from numerically solving a system of coupled ODEs and he also produces 1st, 2nd and 3rd order plots from an analytic solution. The equations he uses are

[image]
[image]

What does it mean to solve this equation to 1st, 2nd and 3rd order, and how would you go about doing it? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Related by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/392398/25301

Comment: @KyleKanos In that question I'm referring to the numerical method however in this I'm talking about the other 3 lines in the plot calculated from the above analytic solution, I don't really understand what it means or how to solve this to 1st, 2nd and 3rd order

Comment: I'm aware of the difference, I'm only adding a link so that interested parties could see both questions in context since they're about similar subjects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function for $w(a)$ given in Tsujikawa's paper is a common parametrisation of the equation of state, known as the CPL parametrisation, after Chevallier, Polarski and Linder.

First, second and third order here means letting $n$ in the sum $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}$ equal 1, 2 and 3; i.e. first order means $n$ is 1, second order has terms with $n=1$ and $n=2$ and third order means you get terms where $n=1$, 2 and 3.

(As an aside, I have never seen this parametrisation used beyond first order).